# What does 294 mean in the HTTP status code 500 0 0 294?

Tags: iis, http-status-codes

I've got following question: I received an HTTP Code 500 0 0 294. I googled but I couldn't find what 294 means. Could you help me? I know that 500 means sc-status 0 means sc-substatus and the second 0 means sc-win32-status.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/w3c-logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should mean **time-taken**, the time-taken field measures the length of time that it takes for a request to be processed.

In order to further confirm your problem, you can also check the field you selected in iis logging.

[image]